# update web.config depend on environments

Tags: sharepoint-server, wcf

I have written feature which updates web.config in inetpub folder under default port 80. It updates web.config with service model. This is not complete code but some code in featureeventreceiver

```
string endpointbindings = @"<system.serviceModel>
                        <bindings>
                            <wsHttpBinding>
                            <binding name=""CustomBinding_ICalcService"">
                                <security mode=""None"" />
                            </binding>
                            </wsHttpBinding>
                        </bindings>
                        <client>
                            <endpoint address=""http://myservice/CalcService.svc""
                                binding=""wsHttpBinding"" bindingConfiguration=""CustomBinding_ICalcService""
                                contract=""CalcService.ICalcService"" name=""CustomBinding_ICalcService"" />
                        </client>
                        </system.serviceModel>";

        webApplication = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;

        webApplication .Update();

        webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
```

Now i want to depoy this package in different environments like Test env, Integration env and Production env. I want to change service model with different endpoint address as per environment where solution will be deployed. How i identify if its production env or test env or integration env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to automate this

1. Identify current URL and put `if..else` condition to load appropriate `endpoint` address
2. Store `endpointbindings` xml in a list (hidden from end user) or read it from Web Property Bag(User SharePoint Designer or PowerShell for setting the value). On feature activation read it from that list/property bag and make the update in web config file.